# Unable to await javascript function call before moving to the next line

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I am having difficulty being able to await a javascript function before moving on to the next line of code, which is what shows up in the console.  I need to await the function before any other code is executed.  The function is called **setProjectName** and it is fired from the onclick of an input element (type = button).  I need to await to completion of the **checkDirectory** function.  As an fyi, I have tried using a `Promise` in the setProjectName function, but that failed to work.  However, it may simply be an issue of my limited knowledge of how promises work.

The following is my code:

```js
async function setProjectName() {
  var projectName = $("#project_name").val();
  var trimName = $.trim(projectName);
  if (!hasWhiteSpace(trimName)) {
    //onError = false;
    if (hasValidCharacters(trimName)) {
      var onError = await checkDirectory(trimName);
      console.log('After checkDirectory: ' + onError);
      if (onError === true) {
        return;
      }
      //onError = false;
      $("#error").text("");
      document.cookie = "ProjectName=" + trimName + "; path=/";
      console.log('after set cookie');
    } else {
      //onError = true;
      $("#error").text("Project name cannot contain special characters!");
    }
  } else {
    //onError = true;
    $("#error").text("Project name cannot contain spaces!");
  }
}

async function checkDirectory(projectName) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var onError = false;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["checkDirUrl"] %>" + "/" + projectName,
                //async: false,
                success: async function (result) {
                    if (result === "folder exists")
                    {
                        //if (confirm('The project name already exists!  Do you wish to delete the project?')) {
                        if (await onConfirm() === 1) {
                            console.log('After deleteDemo');
                            $("#<%= btnHiddenDelete.ClientID %>").click();
                            resolve(1);
                        } else {
                            onError = true;
                            $("#error").text("Project name already exists!");
                        }
                    } else {
                        window.location = ("/Database.aspx");
                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    onError = true;
                    $("#error").text("Error accessing project folder!");
                }
            });
            resolve(0);
        });
    }

async function onConfirm() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var confirmBox = $("#confirm");
            
            confirmBox.show();
            confirmBox.find($("#yes_btn")).click(function () {
                confirmBox.hide();
                resolve(1);
            });
            confirmBox.find($("#no_btn")).click(function () {
                confirmBox.hide();
                resolve(0);
            });
        });

    }
```

```html
<input id="continue" class="btn btn-default" type="button" style="margin-left: 10px;" value="Continue" onclick="setProjectName();" disabled>
```

Comment: If the function returns a promise explicitly, don't declare it with `await`.

Comment: I guess your problem is not that it does not "await" for the end of the execution of your `checkDirectory` function. It actually is! I think your real problem is that it does not await your ajax call to return. This is because you resolve your promise before your ajax call has the chance to return a success / error message. Look at your `resolve(0)`

Comment: @Bastien Where should the `resolve(0)` go or what is the problem with it.  I must be missing something.  As I said, my knowledge of promises is limited.

Comment: You have mixed all sorts of stuff here that shouldn't be mixed.  First off `$.ajax()` already returns a promise so you can just use that promise and don't need `return new Promise()` and don't need `async`.  Then, you're using plain callbacks with `$.ajax()` when you should use `.then()` and `.catch()` on the promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a very mixed programming model.  You're mixing up promises, await, asynchronous callbacks, manually created (and unnecessary) promises, async, etc...  My suggestion is to completely switch over to a promise-based design and use the built-in promise that `$.ajax()` already returns.  Switch the ajax callbacks to use promise resolve/reject.

Then, simplify error handling so that `checkDirectory()` either resolves (if successful) or rejects (if there's an error) and the `error.message` is what you would display to the user.  You currently have error display in both `checkDirectory()` and `setProjectName()` which I think really complicates the design.  I'd suggest combining error display all into `setProjectName()` so that `checkDirectory()` is just a utility function that gives you a result and errors are all handled in `setProjectName()`.

```
// resolves if no error (resolved value is path to redirect to (if not empty))
// rejects if error, e.message in rejection reason is the error message string
async function checkDirectory(projectName) {
    let result;
    try {
        result = await $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["checkDirUrl"] %>" + "/" + projectName,
        });
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error("Error accessing project folder!", { cause: e });
    }
    if (result === "folder exists") {
        if (await deleteDemo() === 1) {
            $("#<%= btnHiddenDelete.ClientID %>").click();
        } else {
            throw new Error("Project name already exists!")
        }
    } else {
        // tell caller to redirect to new page
        return "/Database.aspx";
    }
}

async function setProjectName() {
    try {
        const projectName = $("#project_name").val();
        const trimName = projectName.trim();
        if (hasWhiteSpace(trimName)) {
            throw new Error("Project name cannot contain spaces!");
        }
        if (!hasValidCharacters(trimName)) {
            throw new Error("Project name cannot contain special characters!");
        }
        const redirect = await checkDirectory(trimName);
        if (redirect) {
            window.location = redirect;
            return;
        }
        $("#error").text("");
        document.cookie = "ProjectName=" + trimName + "; path=/";
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        $("#error").text(e.message);
    }
}
```

You don't show the code for `deleteDemo()` and that might need a bit of fixing up too.

Note, in all this code, we display errors to the user in one place with one line of code as all the places the generate errors just throw an error with a custom message which we can then catch all those exceptions/rejections in one place.

Comment: Everything appears to work and it is much cleaner. Thank you for that. The only problem that still exists is that the page is refreshing at the end. This is preventing any messages from being displayed. It also doesn't call the hidden Delete button when a "folder exists." As an fyi, the Delete button spawns a C# code behind function. Btw, I also changed the name of the `deleteDemo()` function and changed it to `onConfirm()`, which I included in my code above. @jfriend00

Comment: @Weequay - Page refreshing would have something to do with how these functions are triggered/called (probably a form).  You'd have to show that part of things for us to contribute to that part.  `onConfirm()` looks OK to me.  Slight nit in that if it gets used more than once, it leaves `.click()` handlers attached and they can build up over time.

Comment: Thanks again.  I took care of the page refreshing by two strategic placements of `event.preventDefault()`.  It seems to get the job done for me. @jfriend00